# Can I bring the result from a function to another function?

Tags: visual-c++

This is a part from my math quiz program.I try to code a math quiz for my assignment and i want to do a final report for my math quiz as shown as (int report()).When i run the program, it said title()(in the modeadd()) too few argument to call.When I change the title() inside modeadd() same as int title(),
I cannot back to menu and it direct go to report.How can i solve this.

```
void main()
{   
    int add, minus, times, divide;

    menu(&add, &minus, &times, &divide);
    report(add, minus, times, divide);

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}

int menu(add, minus, times, divide)
{
    int choice;

        printf("\t\t\t\t\t WELCOME TO THE MATH QUIZ.\n\a");
        printf("\t\t\t IF YOU ARE READY, ENTER '1' FOR YES. IF NOT, ENTER '2' FOR NO.\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);


        while (choice >= 3 || choice <= 0)
            {
                printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
                printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
                scanf("%d", &choice);
                rewind(stdin);
                printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
            }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            title(add, minus, times, divide);
            break;

        default:
            printf("\t\t\t THANK YOU. WELCOME YOU TO TRY WHEN YOU ARE READY.");
        }
         return choice;
     }

    int title(int*add, int*minus, int*times, int*divide)
     {
        int choice;

    printf("PLEASE CHOOSE THE TITLE YOU WANT CHALLENGE.\n");
    printf("1. ADDITION\n2. SUBTRACTION\n3. MULTIPLICATION\n4. DIVISION\n");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (choice >= 5 || choice <= 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
}

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 1, ADDITION\n");
            printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
            (*add)++;
            modeadd();
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 2, SUBTRACTION\n");
            printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
            (*minus)++;
            modeminus();
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 3, MULTIPLICATION\n");
            printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
            (*times)++;
            modetimes();
            break;

        default:
            printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 4, DIVISION\n");
            printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
            (*divide)++;
            modedivide();
            break;
        }

    return choice;
 } 

int modeadd()
{
    int choice;

    printf("PLEASE CHOOSE THE DIFFICULT YOU WANT CHALLENGE FOR ADDITION.\n");
    printf("1. BEGINNER\n2. INTERMEDIATE\n3. ADVANCED\n4. QUIT TO MENU\n");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (choice <= 0 || choice >= 5)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
    }

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 1, BEGINNER.\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        ABeg();
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf("YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 2, INTERMEDIATE.\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        AInter();
    }

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        printf("YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 3, ADVANCED.\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        AAdv();
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        printf("YOU HAVE CHOOSE TO BACK TO MENU. ");
        title();
    }

    return 0;
}

//Addition beginner question
int ABeg()
{
    int    response, i, corAns, wrongAns, num2, num1;
    double answer, correct;

    printf("PLEASE ENTER THE NUMBER OF QUESTION YOU WANT TO TRY : ");
    scanf("%d", &response);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (response < 0)
    {
        printf("PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER : ");
        scanf("%d", &response);
        rewind(stdin);
    }

    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR ANSWER.\n");

    if (response == 0)
    {
        printf("\nTHANKS FOR PLAYING!!!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        corAns = 0;
        wrongAns = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= response; i++)
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            num1 = rand() % 21;
            num2 = rand() % 21;
            correct = num1 + num2;

            printf("\n%d. %d + %d = ", i, num1, num2);
            scanf("%lf", &answer);
            rewind(stdin);

            if (answer == correct)
            {
                printf("I KNOW YOU WILL ANSWERED IT CORRECTLY.\n");
                corAns++;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("SORRY BUT GOOD TRY. THE CORRECT ANSWER IS %.0f.\n", correct);
                wrongAns++;
            }
        }

        printf("\nYOUR RESULT\n");
        printf("===========\n");
        printf("CORRECT ANSWER = %d QUESTION\n", corAns);
        printf("INCORRECT ANSWER = %d QUESTION\n", wrongAns);

        if (corAns == response)
        {
            printf("YOU ARE SO HIGHLY INTELLIGENT :). YOU GET THEM ALL RIGHT!!!\n");
            nextadd();
        }
        else if (corAns == wrongAns)
        {
            printf("GOOD TRY BUT YOU ARE NEARLY FAIL. KEEP WORKING HARDER AND YOU WILL DO BETTER NEXT TIME.\n");
            failadd();
        }
        else if (corAns > wrongAns)
        {
            printf("YOUR CORRECT ANSWER IS ABOVE HALF. GREAT JOB! XD. PLAY THE GAME AGAIN SOON.\n");
            nextadd();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("YOU HAVE FAIL IN THIS MATH QUIZ :(. PLEASE DO THE REVISION.\n");
            failadd();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}    

//Asking after addition question
int nextadd()
{
    int choice;

    printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("DID YOU WANT TO CHALLENGE HARDER QUESTION? OR DIFFERENT ARITHMETIC? OR ELSE.\n");
    printf("1. CHALLENGE SAME OR DIFFERENT LEVEL WITH SAME ARITHMETIC.\n");
    printf("2. DIFFERENT ARITHMETIC.\n");
    printf("3. NO, I WANT TO QUIT THE QUIZ.\n");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR ANSWER : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (choice >= 4 || choice <= 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
}

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
        modeadd();
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
        title();
        break;
    default:
        printf("THANK YOU FOR YOUR PLAYING.");
    }

    return 0;
}

int report(int add, int minus, int times, int divide)
{
    printf("\n============\n");
    printf("FINAL REPORT\n");
    printf("============\n");
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY ADDITION FOR %d TIMES\n", add);
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY SUBTRACTION FOR %d TIMES\n", minus);
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY MULTIPLICATION FOR %d TIMES\n", times);
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY DIVISION FOR %d TIMES\n", divide);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly welcome to StackOverflow.

When asking a question concerning an error, it is helpful, if you say what the error is, rather than just state that there is an error.

In your case, however, I presume from your code, that your "error" is that, regardless of how many times you play, your report shows that you have played 0 times in each category.

This is because of scope. You are declaring variables add, minus, times and divide in both title() and report().  These variables are therefore local only to these routines and are effectively lost when control passes from them.  Your report only shows 0s, because that is the only value in report() that these variables contain.

To fix this you need to do one of two things; either include your code within a class and declare the variables as fields of that class and remove the declarations from title() and report(), or declare them as variables in main() and pass them by reference to menu() (and in turn to title()) and report(). You need to pass by reference since otherwise the called routine only gets a copy of the value, which means that any change to the variable would be lost on exit from the called routine.

EDIT

Just had a bit of spare time, so I was able to revise your code.  This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()
{
    int add, minus, times, divide;
    add = minus = times = divide = 0;
    int choice = 1;
    while (choice == 1)
    {
        choice = menu(&add, &minus, &times, &divide);
    }
    report(add, minus, times, divide);

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}

int menu(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    int choice;

    printf("\t\t\t\t\t WELCOME TO THE MATH QUIZ.\n\a");
    printf("\t\t\t IF YOU ARE READY, ENTER '1' FOR YES. IF NOT, ENTER '2' FOR NO.\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);


    while (choice >= 3 || choice <= 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        title(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;

    default:
        printf("\t\t\t THANK YOU. WELCOME YOU TO TRY WHEN YOU ARE READY.");
    }
    return choice;
}

void failadd(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    return;
}

int modeadd(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    int choice;

    printf("PLEASE CHOOSE THE DIFFICULT YOU WANT CHALLENGE FOR ADDITION.\n");
    printf("1. BEGINNER\n2. INTERMEDIATE\n3. ADVANCED\n4. QUIT TO MENU\n");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (choice <= 0 || choice >= 5)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
    }

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 1, BEGINNER.\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        ABeg(add, minus, times, divide);
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf("YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 2, INTERMEDIATE.\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        AInter(add, minus, times, divide);
    }

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        printf("YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 3, ADVANCED.\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        AAdv(add, minus, times, divide);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        printf("YOU HAVE CHOOSE TO BACK TO MENU. ");
        title(add, minus, times, divide);
    }

    return 0;
}

//Addition beginner question
int ABeg(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    int    response, i, corAns, wrongAns, num2, num1;
    double answer, correct;

    printf("PLEASE ENTER THE NUMBER OF QUESTION YOU WANT TO TRY : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &response);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (response < 0)
    {
        printf("PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &response);
        rewind(stdin);
    }

    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR ANSWER.\n");

    if (response == 0)
    {
        printf("\nTHANKS FOR PLAYING!!!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        (*add)++;
        corAns = 0;
        wrongAns = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= response; i++)
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            num1 = rand() % 21;
            num2 = rand() % 21;
            correct = num1 + num2;

            printf("\n%d. %d + %d = ", i, num1, num2);
            scanf_s("%lf", &answer);
            rewind(stdin);

            if (answer == correct)
            {
                printf("I KNOW YOU WILL ANSWERED IT CORRECTLY.\n");
                corAns++;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("SORRY BUT GOOD TRY. THE CORRECT ANSWER IS %.0f.\n", correct);
                wrongAns++;
            }
        }

        printf("\nYOUR RESULT\n");
        printf("===========\n");
        printf("CORRECT ANSWER = %d QUESTION\n", corAns);
        printf("INCORRECT ANSWER = %d QUESTION\n", wrongAns);

        if (corAns == response)
        {
            printf("YOU ARE SO HIGHLY INTELLIGENT :). YOU GET THEM ALL RIGHT!!!\n");
            nextadd(add, minus, times, divide);
        }
        else if (corAns == wrongAns)
        {
            printf("GOOD TRY BUT YOU ARE NEARLY FAIL. KEEP WORKING HARDER AND YOU WILL DO BETTER NEXT TIME.\n");
            failadd(add, minus, times, divide);
        }
        else if (corAns > wrongAns)
        {
            printf("YOUR CORRECT ANSWER IS ABOVE HALF. GREAT JOB! XD. PLAY THE GAME AGAIN SOON.\n");
            nextadd(add, minus, times, divide);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("YOU HAVE FAIL IN THIS MATH QUIZ :(. PLEASE DO THE REVISION.\n");
            failadd(add, minus, times, divide);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int AInter(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    return 0;
}

int AAdv(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    return 0;
}
//Asking after addition question

int nextadd(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    int choice;

    printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("DID YOU WANT TO CHALLENGE HARDER QUESTION? OR DIFFERENT ARITHMETIC? OR ELSE.\n");
    printf("1. CHALLENGE SAME OR DIFFERENT LEVEL WITH SAME ARITHMETIC.\n");
    printf("2. DIFFERENT ARITHMETIC.\n");
    printf("3. NO, I WANT TO QUIT THE QUIZ.\n");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR ANSWER : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (choice >= 4 || choice <= 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
        modeadd(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
        title(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;
    default:
        printf("THANK YOU FOR YOUR PLAYING.");
    }

    return 0;
}

void modeminus(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    return;
}

void modetimes(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    return;
}

void modedivide(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    return;
}

int title(int * add, int * minus, int * times, int * divide)
{
    int choice;

    printf("PLEASE CHOOSE THE TITLE YOU WANT CHALLENGE.\n");
    printf("1. ADDITION\n2. SUBTRACTION\n3. MULTIPLICATION\n4. DIVISION\n");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    rewind(stdin);

    while (choice >= 5 || choice <= 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n");
        printf("PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n");
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 1, ADDITION\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        modeadd(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 2, SUBTRACTION\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        modeminus(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 3, MULTIPLICATION\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        modetimes(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;

    default:
        printf("YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 4, DIVISION\n");
        printf("\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n");
        modedivide(add, minus, times, divide);
        break;
    }

    return choice;
}

int report(int add, int minus, int times, int divide)
{
    printf("\n============\n");
    printf("FINAL REPORT\n");
    printf("============\n");
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY ADDITION FOR %d TIMES.\n", add);
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY SUBTRACTION FOR %d TIMES.\n", minus);
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY MULTIPLICATION FOR %d TIMES.\n", times);
    printf("YOU HAVE PLAY DIVISION FOR %d TIMES.\n", divide);

    return 0;
}
```

A few things to note.  In c there is no such thing as "pass-by-reference", instead you pass the address of the variable instead (this address is itself passed by value), by prefacing the variable name with &.  Dereferencing the address (with *) means you can manipulate the value located at that address.

I included the call to menu() within in while loop, otherwise the program will end after the first calculation, which is not your intention.

Within menu(), notice that it passes the variables to title() without the &.  This is because the variables that it has received are pointers to an address already, so you can pass them on as is.

title() increments the counters by dereferencing them, e.g. (*add)++;  If you don't dereference them you are incrementing the address, which will not have the effect you want!

I included empty routines for modeadd() etc.  These need completion.

HTH

REVISION

I have made another change, to demonstrate something else.  I have changed the parameters to report() to ints not addresses of ints.  This is because report() only needs to know the values, it does not increment them.  Note now the difference in the calls to menu() and report() within main().

LATEST CHANGES

add, minus, times and divide are now passed everywhere.  Also I have moved the increment of the add counter to ABeg().  It makes more sense here, because you can make sure that it only gets incremented if the user actually opts to answer some questions!

Comment: Thanks for solving part of my question but my main "error" is mean that went I try to debug my program, it come out a message saying that there was a build error. Then it said that in report(), uninitialized local variable ' add', ' minus', 'times' and 'divide' used. So, i know there may be some missing or misplaced of the code. However, I couldn't found it. I have try too put the add, minus, times and divide as a variable in the main(), title(), menu() but I met the same problem also. So I wanted to know where is my mistake and how can I correct it.

Comment: ok.  To get yours to compile, you need to initialise the variables add, minus etc in report(). To do this just assign them a value 0.  (add = 0;)  The compiler complains because you tried to use the variables in your printf.  However, these variables are not needed anyway, if you follow my other suggestions.  HTH

Comment: Ok. But when I change the int title as your, I also need to change the title() inside the modeadd(). However, this have make I cannot back to the menu when i choose to back to menu(In the modeadd()). Furthermore, if I add the while in the main, at the nextadd(), when i choose to quit the program, it jump to the menu again. What i need to do to solve it.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. StackOverflow was down for a while!  I have made the changes required.  Essentially all I did was to include the add, minus, times and divide variables as parameters to every function.  One important change I made, was to move the (*add)++ to ABeg().  It makes far more sense to do the increment in the routines that actually ask the questions, because then you can be sure that it only gets incremented if at least one question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't,t find any definition for your math function in your code

```
modeadd();
modeminus();
modetimes();
modedivide();
```

Define the above functions in your code and compile the program,

for example

```
void modeadd()
{
int a,b;
printf("Please enter the value for A=");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Please enter the value for B=");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("A+B=%d",a+b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I give here an illustration of how you could do exactly the same using c++ and a class.  Apart from the different syntax for standard input/output, the key difference is that add, minus, times and divide are all private members of the class.  This means that all routines automatically have access to them.  This in turn means you do not have to pass them around the whole time, and also you do not need to concern yourself about passing addresses or values.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MathQuiz
{
public:
    MathQuiz()
    {
        add = minus = times = divide = 0;
    }
    int menu()
    {
        int choice;

        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t WELCOME TO THE MATH QUIZ.\n\a";
        cout << "\t\t\t IF YOU ARE READY, ENTER '1' FOR YES. IF NOT, ENTER '2' FOR NO.\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        while (choice >= 3 || choice <= 0)
        {
            cout << "INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n";
            cout << "PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ";
            cin >> choice;
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n";
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            title();
            break;

        default:
            cout << "\t\t\t THANK YOU. WELCOME YOU TO TRY WHEN YOU ARE READY.";
        }
        return choice;
    }

    int report()
    {
        cout << "\n============\n";
        cout << "FINAL REPORT\n";
        cout << "============\n";
        cout << "YOU HAVE PLAY ADDITION FOR " + to_string(add) + " TIMES.\n";
        cout << "YOU HAVE PLAY SUBTRACTION FOR " + to_string(minus) + " TIMES.\n";
        cout << "YOU HAVE PLAY MULTIPLICATION FOR " + to_string(times) + " TIMES.\n";
        cout << "YOU HAVE PLAY DIVISION FOR " + to_string(divide) + " TIMES.\n";

        return 0;
    }


private:
    int add, minus, times, divide;

    void failadd()
    {
        return;
    }

    int modeadd()
    {
        int choice;

        cout << "PLEASE CHOOSE THE DIFFICULT YOU WANT CHALLENGE FOR ADDITION.\n";
        cout << "1. BEGINNER\n2. INTERMEDIATE\n3. ADVANCED\n4. QUIT TO MENU\n";
        cout << "PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        while (choice <= 0 || choice >= 5)
        {
            cout << "INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n";
            cout << "PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ";
            cin >> choice;
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n";
        }

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 1, BEGINNER.\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            ABeg();
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cout << "YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 2, INTERMEDIATE.\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            AInter();
        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "YOUR CHOICE IS NUMBER 3, ADVANCED.\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            AAdv();
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            cout << "YOU HAVE CHOOSE TO BACK TO MENU. ";
            title();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    //Addition beginner question
    int ABeg()
    {
        int    response, i, corAns, wrongAns, num2, num1;
        double answer, correct;

        cout << "PLEASE ENTER THE NUMBER OF QUESTION YOU WANT TO TRY : ";
        cin >> response;
        system("cls");

        while (response < 0)
        {
            cout << "PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER : ";
            cin >> response;
            system("cls");
        }

        cout << "PLEASE ENTER YOUR ANSWER.\n";

        if (response == 0)
        {
            cout << "\nTHANKS FOR PLAYING!!!\n";
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            add++;
            corAns = 0;
            wrongAns = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= response; i++)
            {
                srand(time(0));
                num1 = rand() % 21;
                num2 = rand() % 21;
                correct = num1 + num2;

                cout << to_string(i) + ". " + to_string(num1) + " \+ " + to_string(num2) + " = ";
                cin >> answer;
                system("cls");

                if (answer == correct)
                {
                    cout << "I KNOW YOU WILL ANSWERED IT CORRECTLY.\n";
                    corAns++;
                }

                else
                {
                    cout << "SORRY BUT GOOD TRY. THE CORRECT ANSWER IS " + to_string(correct) + "\n";
                    wrongAns++;
                }
            }

            cout << "\nYOUR RESULT\n";
            cout << "===========\n";
            cout << "CORRECT ANSWER = " + to_string(corAns) + " QUESTION\n";
            cout << "INCORRECT ANSWER = " + to_string(wrongAns) + " QUESTION\n";

            if (corAns == response)
            {
                cout << "YOU ARE SO HIGHLY INTELLIGENT :). YOU GET THEM ALL RIGHT!!!\n";
                nextadd();
            }
            else if (corAns == wrongAns)
            {
                cout << "GOOD TRY BUT YOU ARE NEARLY FAIL. KEEP WORKING HARDER AND YOU WILL DO BETTER NEXT TIME.\n";
                failadd();
            }
            else if (corAns > wrongAns)
            {
                cout << "YOUR CORRECT ANSWER IS ABOVE HALF. GREAT JOB! XD. PLAY THE GAME AGAIN SOON.\n";
                nextadd();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "YOU HAVE FAIL IN THIS MATH QUIZ :(. PLEASE DO THE REVISION.\n";
                failadd();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int AInter()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int AAdv()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //Asking after addition question

    int nextadd()
    {
        int choice;

        cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
        cout << "DID YOU WANT TO CHALLENGE HARDER QUESTION? OR DIFFERENT ARITHMETIC? OR ELSE.\n";
        cout << "1. CHALLENGE SAME OR DIFFERENT LEVEL WITH SAME ARITHMETIC.\n";
        cout << "2. DIFFERENT ARITHMETIC.\n";
        cout << "3. NO, I WANT TO QUIT THE QUIZ.\n";
        cout << "PLEASE ENTER YOUR ANSWER : ";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        while (choice >= 4 || choice <= 0)
        {
            cout << "INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n";
            cout << "PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ";
            cin >> choice;
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n";
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n";
            modeadd();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n";
            title();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "THANK YOU FOR YOUR PLAYING.";
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void modeminus()
    {
        return;
    }

    void modetimes()
    {
        return;
    }

    void modedivide()
    {
        return;
    }

    int title()
    {
        int choice;

        cout << "PLEASE CHOOSE THE TITLE YOU WANT CHALLENGE.\n";
        cout << "1. ADDITION\n2. SUBTRACTION\n3. MULTIPLICATION\n4. DIVISION\n";
        cout << "PLEASE ENTER YOUR CHOICE : ";
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");

        while (choice >= 5 || choice <= 0)
        {
            cout << "INVALID NUMBER, PLEASE TRY AGAIN.\n";
            cout << "PLEASE RE-ENTER AGAIN : ";
            cin >> choice;
            system("cls");
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n";
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 1, ADDITION\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            modeadd();
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 2, SUBTRACTION\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            modeminus();
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 3, MULTIPLICATION\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            modetimes();
            break;

        default:
            cout << "YOU CHOICE IS NUMBER 4, DIVISION\n";
            cout << "\n----------------------------------PAGE BREAK------------------------------------\n\n";
            modedivide();
            break;
        }

        return choice;
    }


};

int main()
{
    MathQuiz quiz;
    int choice = 1;
    while (choice == 1)
    {
        choice = quiz.menu();
    }
    quiz.report();

    cout << "\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```